# How to delete a clearcase branch with a single command?

Tags: version-control, branch, clearcase

I've accidentally created a branch with the wrong config spec and I've made a merge in there that wasn't meant to be done. Is there a way to remove this branch like it never existed, with one and only command? There are no checked-out files in the branch.

I could go through all files and do it manually since there are only 3 files that were merged. But what if there were 3000 instead of 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and delete the byrtpe (branch type) with [`cleartool rmtype brtype:xxx`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmtype.htm).

That is possible only if you are talking about a brand new branch, which was used only in this instance (that is, where you need to delete *all* instances of that branch *type*: an instance of a branch type is a branch created to reference a version at a checkin).

Then (if the *only* versions in that branches are the wrong merged ones), you could do:

```
cleartool rmtype -rmall brtype:yourBranch@\avob
```

Again, that is a dangerous command, and should only be used for a new branch with a few versions.

The `-rmall` will first remove all branch type instances (ie the actual branches, and their associated versions and labels).
Then the branch type itself will be removed.

Comment: You are the savior for those very few of us doomed to use clearcase. Branch is brand new, although I've made a merge (and checked the files in) from another branch. What I don't understand is what `this instance` refers to if you could explain. I have removed the branch from the CC explorer so I can't test immediately. Your record though in similar questions does not leave me any doubts.

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis Sorry for the delay. I have edited my answer accordingly, to explain why an "instance" is when it comes to a branch type.

Comment: What delay? ;) Thanks, I understand now. (Well I _think_, it's clearcase after all, I can never be sure :D )

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis Yes, a brtype is the template from which a branch is created. Once that branch is created, it is an instance of the brtype.