# Is it possible to remove the label from entire version tree?

Tags: clearcase

From every branch and node.
Not only in branch of current view.

I have tried using "cleartool rmlabel -rec YOUR_LABEL yourDirectory" . but it removes only current view of version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try instead to remove the entire label *type*:

```
cleartool rmtype -rmall yourlabel@\avob
```

But be careful, that would remove all instances of that label anywhere in that repo.
See another example of `rmtype` with "[How to delete a clearcase branch with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48428069/6309)" using find and [`cleartool rmlabel`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmlabel.htm).

Since you don't want to remove the label in the all vob, only in a given folder, you need to apply a slower solution, [searching files with that label in your folder *and* subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221254/6309):

```
cd /path/to/your/folder
cleartool find . -version "{lbtype(LABEL)}" -print
```

If the above line do print version for files in your folder *and* your subfolder, then try:

```
cd /path/to/your/folder
cleartool find . -version "{lbtype(LABEL)}" -exec "cleartool rmlabel YOUR_LABEL \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

Comment: I tried above "cleartool rmtype -rmall MYLABEL C:\user\vob\old" in my vob. but i have faced error. (path name not found/ Not an object in a vob).

Comment: I want to delete a label from particular folder of my vob. Not from entire vob.

Comment: @Sudhakar.NSabari The syntax would be `cleartool rmtype -rmall yourlabel@\avob`, no space. And that would remove the label for the *all* vob, so that is not what you want. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Sudhakar.NSabari I have edited the answer accordingly.